# meta viewport issue in iPhone but working on android

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, web

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-1200">`

Website view does not show according to above width on iPhone but working fine on android

Answer (score 0):

Usually iphones have problems with view port. i see that there is some problem with the view port you are using. on android and other PC, browsers reads and fixes viewport automatically. but not in phones so you need to fix your view port metatag
. try the one I gave below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```